# In a VBA if-statement, insert part of the statement through a variable

Tags: ms-access, vba

In VBA (in an MS Access project) I want to define an if-statement where part of the statement is stored in a variable.

To make my issue clear, here is a simple example:

```
Sub Test_String_Insertion_Into_IfStatement()

   Dim strInsert As String

   strInsert = "10 > 5"  ' Or any other stuff that would return "TRUE"

   If "" & "'"strInsert"'" & "" Then
      Debug.Print "Hurray, it works!"
   Else
      Debug.Print "Sorry, my friend. Try something else..."
   End If

End Sub
```

Now, the problem is, this does not work. The trick is, I suppose, finding the correct combination of ampersands, quotation marks, apostrophos, and/or Chr(34).

I have made many experiments, testing all variations I could possibly imagine, but I have not found a working combination so far. Most of what I tested returns a "Type mismatch" error.

**The real-world application...**

The example above is rather simplified. In my real-world task, I want to insert a much longer string as part of the if-statement. Here is one of my real-world if statements that finally shall be replaced by something that uses a variable to insert the larger part of the statement (this is: everything except the proper "If" and "Then"):

```
If oRs.Fields(strTitField) Like "*" & arrWCs(r).varTERM1 & "*" Then
```

It uses fields of a recordset and a user-defined variable type (array).

Please note that the section of the if-statement that I want to insert variable-wise *has itself quotation marks and ampersands*! (The real-world if-statement has proven to work. But now I want to insert this into my if-statement using a variable.)

The purpose is, using a variable-insert I could very quickly switch between multiple if-statements, depending on the need in the overall function.)

For convenience, I add a simple example that uses ampersands and quotes in the if statement:

```
Sub Test_String_Insertion_Into_IfStatement_2()

   Dim strIfClause As String
   Dim strXYZ As String

   strXYZ = "ouse"
   strInsert = "'Mouse' Like '*' & strXYZ & '*'" ' Just a guess, doesn't work

   If "" & """strInsert""" & "" Then
         'The resulting if-statement should be: 
         'If "Mouse" Like "*" & strXYZ & "*" Then '(Taken as such, this works!)
      Debug.Print "Good!"
   Else
      Debug.Print "Not good!"
   End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Use the `Application.Evaluate()` method. For example, `str = "10 > 5"` passed in `Application.Evaluate(str)` will return a `Boolean True`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the following solution. As suggested by the expert contributors, it uses the Eval() method.

```
Dim strTest As String
strTest = "'" & oRs.Fields(strTitField).value & "' Like '*" & arrudtWCs(r).varTERM1 & "*' And '" & oRs.Fields(strTitField).value & "' Like '*" & arrudtWCs(r).varTERM2 & "*' And '" & oRs.Fields(strTitField).value & "' Like '*" & arrudtWCs(r).varTERM3 & "*'"

If Eval(strTest) Then
'Do something
End If
```

- oRs is a recordset,  based on one of the tables in the Access
  database.
- arrudtWCs(r) is an array of user-defined type, with elements
  varTERM1, varTERM2, varTERM3 and so on.
- strTitField is a string variable holding the name of the table field to be used. The variable must not be declared here, because it is part of the procedure's parameters when the procedure is called.

The Eval(strTest) evaluates the (series of) condition(s) defined in the strTest-string, i.e. concretely it compares values from the arrudtWCs-array with field values in the active line of the recordset, and if the condition is found to be met, some further action is taken.

The main problem was finding the correct use of apostrophs, quotes and ampersands.